# Solve $\left(1+{y'}^2 \right) y''' - 3{y''}^2 y' = 0$ with Legendre Transformation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have got a question concerning the use of Legendre Transformation for solving ordinary differential equations. 
We did this stuff in an ordinary differential equations class. The professor stated the definition. Unfortunately I could not find any examples of this on the web.

Now, I am going to repeat the class in order to specify the topic.

To begin with, let's clarify the notation: Derivatives with respect to $t$ are denoted by dots above letters. Derivatives with respect to $k$ are denoted by an apostrophe. 
    Let $y(t)$ be the solution of an ODE. Equation 1 is the definition of the Legendre Transformation.
    \begin{align}
 y(t)&=kt-n(k)\\
 \therefore \dot{y}&=k\\
 \therefore \dot{y}&=k+t \dot{k} - \dot{n}\\
 \therefore \frac{dn}{dt}&=x \frac{dk}{dt}\\
 \therefore \frac{dn}{dk}&=t\\
 \end{align}
    So,
    \begin{equation}
  \frac{d^2 y}{dt^2}=\frac{dk}{dt}=\frac{1}{\frac{dt}{dk}}=\frac{1}{\frac{d(\frac{dn}{dk})}{dk}}=\frac{1}{\frac{d^2 n}{dk^2}}=\frac{1}{n''}
 \end{equation}
    Up to here, I think I understand pretty much everything. $k$ is the slope of $y$ and $-n$ is the distance from the origin to the point of intersection of the tangent of $y$ with the $y$ axis.

Now comes my real question:

How to solve this ODE via Legendre Transformation?
    $$\left(1+{y'}^2 \right) y''' - 3{y''}^2 y' = 0$$

I have no idea how to do this and would be glad for any help. 
    Furthermore, why can't I find any example of a solution of an ODE via a Legendre Transform?

Comment: The most obvious question would seem to be what that ODE looks like upon making the above substitution. (Though, the above ODE is actually a function of $y'$ alone. So it may be the case that, say, $y'(t)$ is what should be Legendre-transformed. Can't tell for sure.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(1+y'^2)y'''-3y''^2y'=0$$
Transformation : $\quad y'(t)=z \quad\to\quad (1+z^2)z''-3z'^2z=0$
$$\frac{z''}{z'}=3\frac{z'z}{1+z^2}$$
$\frac{3}{2}\ln|1+z^2|=\ln|z'|+$constant.
$$(1+z^2)^{3/2}=c_1z'=c_1\frac{dz}{dt} \quad\to\quad dt=c_1\frac{dz}{(1+z^2)^{3/2}}$$
$$t=c_1\int \frac{dz}{(1+z^2)^{3/2}} =-c_1\frac{z}{\sqrt{1+z^2}}+c_2$$
$(t-c_2)^2(1+z^2)=c_1^2z^2 \quad\to\quad z^2=\frac{(t-c_2)^2}{c_1^2-(t-c_2)^2}$
$$z=\pm\frac{t-c_2}{\sqrt{c_1^2-(t-c_2)^2}}$$
$$y=\pm\int \frac{(t-c_2)dt}{\sqrt{c_1^2-(t-c_2)^2}} = \pm\sqrt{c_1^2-(t-c_2)^2}+c_3$$